# How to corretly use AdressSanitizer

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management, visual-studio-2019, address-sanitizer

I have a program in CPP that I'd like to debug because it crashes at some point at the end of a function when exiting the function with the following error message "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'dim' was corrupted." (note that when I print "dim" it prints the correct value).

So I tried to debug the code using AdressSanitizer (VS 20109) expecitng it to give maybe a more precise error message because that's what I understood address sanitizer does from the doc.

But when I launch my code with AdressSanitizer (vs2019), it doesn't crash anymore, goes through the code perfectly and displays vague error message (0xE0736171 : Acess violation at address 0x000003B3160F1000.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170

Looking at the following link, AdressSanitizer is supposed to give a precise stacktrace when encountering an error, but I did not expect nor understood that it would ignore (or correct?) the memory problem by itself

So what exacly does AdressSanitizer and what am I doing wrong? am I using it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are not necessarily doing something wrong (i mean after all your code has undefined behavior) but you didnt include enough details to say

Comment: Well I thought address Sanitizer was about having a stack trace of the error, but the code systematically crashes at the same place with same error if I don't have the address Sanitizer, and never crash nor show a complete stacktrace (as shown in the link) if I have the address sanitizer, therefore I'm guessing the address sanitizer doesn't do what I expect it to do

Comment: Debug or release build and if release did you ask the build system to produce the PDB for the symbols?

Comment: Debug build for both, exactly same configuration just with or without address sanitizer, althought I don't know what PDB for symbol is :x

Comment: I did find how to generate the PDB file, but I don't understand much about it to be honest lol

Comment: Are you running the code in the debugger?

Comment: Microsoft's info on [PDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022) files.

Comment: Yes I'm running the code in debugger, and I checked this also Eljay but didn't help me much :/

Comment: You can test the AdressSanitizer using  sample: [Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'foo' was corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516740/run-time-check-failure-2-stack-around-the-variable-foo-was-corrupted). Will  your problem appear in visual studio 2022? It is better to provide an example.

Comment: My "code problem" is long solved, but I think people didn't get my question, which is what exactly addressSanitizer does, since it was able to make my code work (so it fixed the bug itself) while I thought addressSanitizer would just show a more complete stacktrace